# soap film surface variational problem, How do I find the integration constants?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, calculus-of-variations, hyperbolic-functions

I got the following equation as solution of the soap film surface variational problem

$u(x)= \frac{1}{c_1}\cosh(c_1x+c_2)$

$u(0)=r$, $u(b)=r$

My problem is I can't solve for $c1$ and $c2 $

$c_1r= \cosh(c_2)$

$c_1r= \cosh(c_1b+c_2)$

I am supposed to express $u$ in terms of$ b$ and then analize the limiting behavior for $b>>r$. One of the constants is supposed to be found explicitly and the other one implicitly. I already tried everything. Any help will be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your system of equations, you can set them equal to get
$$\cosh(c_2)=\cosh(c_1b+c_2)$$

To solve from here note that $\cosh(x)=\cosh(y)$ admits two solutions, either $x=y$ or $x=-y$. Can you continue from here?

**Edit:**
So $x=y$ does not give a solution and after plugging in $c_2=-c_1b/2$ we get the implicit equation of $c_1$:
$$c_1r=\cosh(-c_1b/2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{c_1b/2} + e^{-c_1b/2}\right)$$
Now notice that the exponential is growing much faster than the linear term so it seems there is no solution for $b >> r$. This can be formalized by estimating say
$$ 2c_1r > e^{c_1b/2} > c_1b/2$$
which gives $r > b/4$. In other words, if $ b >> r$ the equation has no solution. This corresponds to physical intuition from the soap bubbles. What do you expect the soap film to do if you increase $b/r$?

Comment: ahh, I was trying to do cosh( of a sum)=...., so the first one leads to c1=0, i guess this is not a solution? Not very sure

Comment: The other one is c2=-c1b/2, and if I plug that in in one of the other equations I still get equations were I am not able to solve explicitly fora at least one of the solutions without involving the other

Comment: I get $u(x)=1/c_1 \cosh(c_1x-bc_1/2)$, and $\cosh(c_2)=c_1r     $how do I find the limit for $b/r --> \infty  $with this implicit expressions?